# DNS server using scapy

Tags: python, server, scapy

i wrote a python DNS server using Scapy and i have a problem.
i sniff a DNS packet (by filter to A or PTR types) and than i wanna send a relevant response.

i use two computers and in one of them i use nslookup www.google.com
it shows me "request time out error" - timeout was 2 seconds.
BYW i received this packet and i sent a one!! but the other computer didn't get this on time i guess.

i tried to change the timeout to 20 seconds but it just wait 20 seconds.. and than shows an error..
and my server get the packet after this 20 seconds.

how can i solve this problem and what cause it!!

Thanks from advance :)

here some of my code (in the may relevant parts):

```
def filter_dns(packet):
return DNS in packet and packet[DNS].opcode == 0 and (packet[DNSQR].qtype == 1 or packet[DNSQR].qtype == 12)



server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_socket.bind((MY_IP, PORT))
print "Server started successfully! Waiting for data..."

packets = sniff(count=1, lfilter=filter_dns)

def send_typeA(packet, result):
    mypacket = IP(dst=Ip_Client) / DNS() / DNSRR()
    mypacket[DNSRR].rrname = packet[DNSQR].qname
    mypacket[DNSRR].rdata = result   # result is the ip of the domain name
    mypacket[DNSRR].ttl = 100
    print mypacket.show()
    send(mypacket)
```

Comment: The client will only accept the response if you spoof the server's address and port number.

Comment: how can i do it? i did change the dns defult ip to my server's ip and if it's not work it goes to 8.8.8.8 is this what you mean ?

Comment: You said you're sniffing the packet, so I thought it was being sent to a different IP than your server. Sounds like you need to post your code.

Comment: Have you tried running a packet capture on the client to see if it's receiving the response?

Comment: yep :) i added a part of my code:)

Comment: i added my code so now it will help you guys to see what's wrong